# Laravel empty password being hashed when updating user

Tags: php, laravel, hash, passwords

When I'm updating my model-bound form with

```
$user->update(Input::all())
```

My password field is re-hashed, even when it's empty. I have set my User.php class to automatically hash that field, but shouldn't it be skipped since the field is empty?

Comment: You should consider using `accessors and mutators` `http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use in this case:

```
Input::except('password')
```

so in your controller you could do it this way:

```
if (trim(Input::get('password')) == '') {
   $data = Input::except('password');
}
else {
   $data = Input::all();
}
$user->update($data);
```

However you should consider other possible issues for that. In this case if user send input with `id` name (and anyone can do it even if you don't have such field in your form) he could change easily other users passwords/accounts and destroy your whole data.

You should use in your `User` model at least:

```
protected $guarded = array('id');
```

to protect user id from being changed  during [mass assignment](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#mass-assignment)  but maybe there are also some other fields you would like to protect (you should list them in `$guarded` array.

For me much better option in this case is using standard user updating:

```
$user = User::find($id);

if (trim(Input::get('password')) != '') {
   $user->password = Hash::make(trim(Input::get('password')));
} 
$user->name = Input::get('name');
// and so on - this way you know what you are changing and you won't change something you don't want to change
$user->save();
```

Comment: Ah, got it. One would expect that even if we're setting ::all() Laravel would be smart enough to skip hashing a blank field, but anyway ... this will work. Thanks!

Comment: @user2261056 And Laravel doesn't skip it because maybe sometimes you want to set some text in table to empty string

Comment: Yup, it makes sense - it's just that hashing an empty string should return false and be skipped, in my opinion.

Answer (score 4):

Just as Tom Bird commented, here's some code for an example.

If you use a mutator like `setPasswordAttribute()` method in your model then you can do this:

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{   
    if (!empty($password))
    {
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
    }
}
```

This will prevent a new password from being hashed. This setPasswordAttribute() method is called a "mutator" and became available in Laravel 4.2 from what I see. http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent

Comment: This breaks the build-in password reset function because it will double bcrypt your password

Answer (score 1):

Because you have sent all of the input to the user model it assumes you want to update all fields including the password even though it is an empty string, it is possible to hash an empty string.

You need to check if the password is empty and if it is use `Input::except('password')`

Answer (score 0):

The simple method you can use for this is array_filter. Array_filter filter excludes any empty field. so if you password field is empty then it will not be included in the user update model and when the password field is not included it will not be hashed since mutators and accessors only work when the model has the  given attribute. When you filter it out the fields, the model does not receive the field and thus will not hash. You use it in following way...

```
$user->update(array_filter(Input::all()));
```

or

```
$user->update(array_filter($request->all()));
```

The only problem with this is it will not only exclude password but also all the field that were set empty.

Answer (score -1):

```
public function update($id)
{
    $register = Register::findOrFail($id);
    if (empty(Request::get('password'))) {
        $data = Request::except('password');
    } else {
        $data = Request::all();
    }
    $register->update($data);
    return redirect('register');
}
```